How to Connect Cloudflare Pages CNAME to My Application Endpoint and Customize Auto-Generated CNAME?
I'm using Cloudflare Pages to host my site, and I have a few questions about connecting my custom domain and managing the provided CNAME:
Connecting the CNAME: How can I connect the CNAME provided by Cloudflare Pages to the endpoint of my application? I want to ensure that my custom domain correctly points to my Cloudflare Pages site.
Customizing the CNAME: Cloudflare Pages provides an auto-generated custom domain CNAME with a .pages.dev extension. Is it possible to edit or customize this auto-generated CNAME to better fit my needs?
I appreciate any guidance or best practices on setting this up.

About first question - if your site deployed to the Cloudflare pages, that means Cloudflare will provide you correct record with the .pages.dev extension.
About second question, yes, you can use custom domain records for you pages - you need to create a Custom domains, instruction from Cloudflare site:
To add a custom domain:

Log in to the Cloudflare dashboard.
Select your account in Account Home > Workers & Pages.
Select your Pages project > Custom domains.
Select Set up a domain.
Provide the domain that you would like to serve your Cloudflare
Pages site on and select Continue.

About "edit or customize this auto-generated CNAME" - as I know this is not possible, but you can block any connections to your Cloudflare page via .pages.dev endpoint by using cloudflare zero trust. Please find instructions here.
